SQL Server Deadlock Delete Insert Statement
Both a delete and insert (range) on the same table are causing a deadlock due to contention on the same primary key index. I don't understand why.
The locks taken are RangeS-S by each process and the locks being waited upon are X (for the delete) and RangeI-N (for the insert).
The dbo.UserRole table has a self-referencing foreign key called PrimaryRoleId that refers to a primary key of the same table. Prior to the deadlock delete the statement a similar bulk delete statement is used to delete the parent rows so the former will succeed without a foreign key reference exception.
XML Report:
<deadlock>
<victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process17e4984bc28" />
</victim-list>
<process-list>
    <process id="process17e4984bc28" taskpriority="0" logused="704" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057594065715200 (d154aa88375f)" waittime="164" ownerId="17841945353" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2024-12-26T14:14:27.707" XDES="0x17e2cb18428" lockMode="X" schedulerid="14" kpid="2224" status="suspended" spid="79" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2024-12-26T14:14:27.730" lastbatchcompleted="2024-12-26T14:14:27.737" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.737" clientapp="Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WIN10A-AWAN" hostpid="26352" loginname="PMB" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="17841945353" currentdb="8" currentdbname="PMBridge_Dev" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
        <executionStack>
            <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="22" stmtend="130" sqlhandle="0x02000000aa1dbf36579351bfa10e65f22ff951eaef2f9d1b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                unknown
            </frame>
            <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                unknown
            </frame>
        </executionStack>
        <inputbuf>
            (@ids1 int)DELETE FROM [cs].[UserRole] WHERE UserRoleId in (@ids1)
        </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process17e49683468" taskpriority="0" logused="720" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057594065715200 (ffffffffffff)" waittime="133" ownerId="17841946524" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2024-12-26T14:14:27.723" XDES="0x17d886f4428" lockMode="RangeI-N" schedulerid="7" kpid="4284" status="suspended" spid="75" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2024-12-26T14:14:27.760" lastbatchcompleted="2024-12-26T14:14:27.767" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.767" clientapp="Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WIN10A-AWAN" hostpid="26352" loginname="PMB" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="17841946524" currentdb="8" currentdbname="PMBridge_Dev" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
        <executionStack>
            <frame procname="PMBridge_Dev.cs.p_AssignRole" line="176" stmtstart="15628" stmtend="16676" sqlhandle="0x03000800590ca26ef40b780034b2000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
                insert into cs.UserRole (UserId, RoleId,
                UserLocationTypeID, UserLocationOrgStructureID, UserLocationOrganizationID,
                RoleObjectTypeID, RoleObjectOrgStructureID, RoleObjectProjectID,
                UpdateUserID, UpdateDate, RoleAssignmentTypeId)
                select @userId, RoleId,
                @userLocationTypeId, @userLocationOrgStructureId, @userLocationOrganizationId,
                RoleObjectTypeId, RoleObjectOrgStructureId, RoleObjectProjectId,
                @updateUserId, getdate(), RoleAssignmentTypeId
                from @roleTable
                where PrimaryRoleId is nul
            </frame>
        </executionStack>
        <inputbuf>
            Proc [Database Id = 8 Object Id = 1856113753]
        </inputbuf>
    </process>
</process-list>
<resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594065715200" dbid="8" objectname="PMBridge_Dev.cs.UserRole" indexname="PK_UserRole_1" id="lock17dd353a500" mode="RangeS-S" associatedObjectId="72057594065715200">
        <owner-list>
            <owner id="process17e49683468" mode="RangeS-S" />
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
            <waiter id="process17e4984bc28" mode="X" requestType="convert" />
        </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594065715200" dbid="8" objectname="PMBridge_Dev.cs.UserRole" indexname="PK_UserRole_1" id="lock17c13947580" mode="RangeS-S" associatedObjectId="72057594065715200">
        <owner-list>
            <owner id="process17e4984bc28" mode="RangeS-S" />
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
            <waiter id="process17e49683468" mode="RangeI-N" requestType="convert" />
        </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
</resource-list>
</deadlock>

Here are the indexes on the UserRole table:

/****** Object:  Index [IX_UserRole_PrimaryUserRoleID]    Script Date: 12/27/2024 9:51:14 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserRole_PrimaryUserRoleID] ON [cs].[UserRole]
(
    [PrimaryUserRoleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]


/****** Object:  Index [IX_UserRole_RoleID]    Script Date: 12/27/2024 9:51:22 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserRole_RoleID] ON [cs].[UserRole]
(
    [RoleID] ASC
)
INCLUDE([UserID],[UserLocationTypeID],[UserLocationItemID],[UserLocationOrgStructureID],[UserLocationOrganizationID],[RoleObjectTypeID],[RoleObjectItemID],[RoleObjectOrgStructureID],[RoleObjectProjectID],[UpdateDate],[RoleAssignmentTypeId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** Object:  Index [IX_UserRole_UserID]    Script Date: 12/27/2024 9:51:38 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserRole_UserID] ON [cs].[UserRole]
(
    [UserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** Object:  Index [IX_UserRole_UserLocationOrganizationID]    Script Date: 12/27/2024 9:52:04 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserRole_UserLocationOrganizationID] ON [cs].[UserRole]
(
    [UserLocationOrganizationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** Object:  Index [IX_UserRole_UserLocationOrgStructureID]    Script Date: 12/27/2024 9:52:12 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserRole_UserLocationOrgStructureID] ON [cs].[UserRole]
(
    [UserLocationOrgStructureID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

/****** Object:  Index [PK_UserRole_1]    Script Date: 12/27/2024 9:52:21 AM ******/
ALTER TABLE [cs].[UserRole] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_UserRole_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserRoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]


Here is the @roleTable temporary table definition:

declare @roleTable table (RoleId int, RoleObjectTypeId int,
    RoleObjectValueTypeID int, RoleObjectValueOrgStructureID int, IsOrgStructure int,
    PrimaryRoleId int, RoleAssignmentTypeId int, RoleObjectOrgStructureId int, RoleObjectProjectId int)


I did find the following inner join on the UserRole table in the stored procedure. My guess this is causing the RangeS-S locks but I'm not sure how to optimize it with indexes (?) to reduce the possibility of deadlocks:

    delete r
    from @roleTable r
    inner join cs.UserRole ur on ur.UserID = @userId and ur.RoleID = r.RoleId and ur.RoleAssignmentTypeId = r.RoleAssignmentTypeId
        and ur.RoleObjectTypeID = r.RoleObjectTypeID 
        and ur.RoleObjectItemID = isnull(r.RoleObjectOrgStructureId, 0) + isnull(r.RoleObjectProjectId, 0)
        and ur.UserLocationTypeID = @userLocationTypeId 
        and ur.UserLocationItemID = isnull(@userLocationOrgStructureId, 0) + isnull(@userLocationOrganizationId, 0)



Thanks for th XDL graph, but we also need to see: tables and index definitions for all relevant tables, and please share the query plans for both queries via https://pastetheplan.com. If these are part of outer transactions then please show the code for the whole transaction.

It's very little information, but,  you may use  Temporary Table to grab data-set on insert process, or, simple use hint NOLOCK and see the behavior. You also may use Isolation Level (with snapshot isolation) to reduce this contation, but..  can cause tempDB overhead

Sorry, although I am a full stack developer, my DB "expertise" are limited. I'm not sure I can provide additional code or and am unaware of how to obtain the asked for more information. The deadlock graph (as well as the XML report) says that the deadlock is occurring for the primary key index for the column UserRoleId on the dbo.UserRoleId table. The first process is just trying to delete records by the primary key, while the second is already attempting to insert new records into the same table from a temporary table. Perhaps someone can tell me how the RangeS-S locks come in to play.

I see the table in the graph [cs].[UserRole] and the table variable @roleTable but I see no definition for them. Please show it with indexes and foreign keys. Also the insert query appears cut off, please show the whole thing. For the query plan, you can run those queries in SSMS and get the Actual (or at least the Estimated) execution plan. Right click and copy the plan XML, then paste into the above link.

I would hazard a guess that the self-referencing FK column does not have an index, requiring a full scan to ensure no child rows exist when deleting. Adding that index will probably remove the deadlock, but we really need to see those definitions.

I have updated the post with some of the requested information. The insert query isn't cutoff though. That is what was directly copied from the XML produced by SQL server. But it looks like only the last "l" is cut off from null. Also, it appears that the self-referencing column on the table does have an index on it.

Full table definition please (CREATE TABLE etc), as well as the query plans.
